# meteor - admin package : translating

Tags: javascript, meteor, internationalization, package, admin

I'm starting with MeteorJS, I would like to clarify a question.

Have this package here: https://atmospherejs.com/yogiben/admin
and this: https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin
He is quite complete, I installed all the necessary packages, set up as a small documentation.
I wonder if there is a possibility of putting in **pt-br** lang.

Already would kill a good time of my project if I started with this admin panel in pt-br.
The same developer has a "Meteor Starter" package, but it's coffescript me wrapped around all to read it hahahaha.

Who can help me, I thank you.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive internationalization solution for Meteor

```
meteor add tap:i18n
```

or Check out [here](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n)

If you finding translation from **en** to **pt-br** package, the google translate package is still under development which i found.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i edit the admin package texts ? Sorry, i'm new on Meteor. UPDATE: the tap:i18n package translate all texts in Meteor application ?

Comment: then Fork their package and edit yourself or turn it to support i18n. That's why u can find some "same name" package plus i18n.

such as https://atmospherejs.com/martino/iron-router-i18n & https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router